# mmenu overpainted by slick slider

Tags: mmenu

I am creating a website for a friend as a favour and have hit an impasse trying to find the

I am Using Slick Slider from

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

as a slider (client insisted that I use a slider in design although I feel they look dated)

Anyhow

Got mmenu working quite quickly but I am getting overpainting by the slider in the browser

Trying to figure out what I need to push out with the z-index as nothing seems to make any difference

My source is at

```
    https://github.com/stereocats/jenniferbrickwell/tree/feature/Responsive_Meun_with_mmenu_%2315
```

applicable source code is contained in ...

```
_includes/nav.html
js/main.js
sass/nav.sass
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting overpainting by the slider"? Maybe including a screenshot could help.

Comment: Thanks @Challe I've [published a picture here](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAZKFzPfr99Kaog7305Ev8b4a6r2tXK01L0)